# ¿Reemplazar caracteres con replace?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Espero me puedan apoyar, estoy tratando de remplazar en esta cadena `'2023-04-12 12:00:00.000'` los primero dos caracteres de la hora por ceros `'2023-04-12 00:00:00.000'`,
hay alguna manera de hacerlo? lo intente con replace pero tengo entendido que `Replace()` solo funciona si le especificas el caracter que quieres quitar.
¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo? contanto los caracteres de izquierda a derecha o poniendo un rango como `Remove()`.

En este solo pude eliminar toda la hora:

```
string = "2023-04-12 12:00:00.000".Remove(0, 10);
```

En este si lo pude cambiar pero especificandole el numero:

```
string nuevaFecha = traffic.Key.ToString().Replace("12", "00");
```

Y yo lo que busco es remplazar esos dos primero caracteres de la hora serian el 12 y el 13 y replazarlos por ceros.

Comment: Como tienes el código?

Comment: Puse los ejemplos como lo intente en la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `Substring()` para obtener las partes de la fecha / hora desde una cadena y generar otra:

```
// Cadena original
string fechaOriginal = "2023-04-12 12:00:00.000";

// Reemplazar los primeros dos caracteres de la hora por ceros
string fechaModificada = fechaOriginal.Substring(0, 11) + "00" + fechaOriginal.Substring(13);

// Imprimir la fecha modificada
Console.WriteLine(fechaModificada);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaracoder, me ayudaste muchisimo.

Answer (score 2):

Muchas gracias a la aportación de @jaracoder se pudo resolver el problema, pero no contaba con que el valor de mi tabla era datetime, lo tuve que convertir y me salia el mismo resultado, entonces lo resolví de esta manera pero ya lo realice directamente con SQL:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
//2023-04-13 00:00:00.000
```

Espero alguien le sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya tienes respuestas y solucionaste el problema, me gustaría aprovechar para indicar que las fechas nunca deben tratarse como cadenas, si no con su tipo específico que es `DateTime`.

En este caso en concreto, usando `DateTime` sería trivial obtener el resultado que buscas. La propiedad `Date` contiene la fecha sin el componente horario, que creo que es lo que buscabas. Si luego necesitas mostrarlo por pantalla, un simple `ToString` personalizado te va a permitir hacerlo de la forma que necesites.

Añado un ejemplo de tu caso:

```
string fecha = "2023-04-12 12:00:00.000";
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(fecha).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")); // Devuelve 2023-04-12 00:00:00.000
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(fecha).ToShortDateString()); // Devuelve 4/12/2023 (dependiendo de la cultura)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportacion Piko.

Answer (score 2):

```
string fechaOriginal = "2023-04-12 12:00:00.000";
string sfecha = Convert.ToDateTime(fechaOriginal).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación Jose.